# Action Controller: Exception caught. ArgumentError in my index controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a newbie to rails and am getting an ArgumentError in my application stating the following: Nil location provided. Can't build URI.

Showing /app/app/views/buzzs/_home.html.erb where line #10 raised:

Nil location provided. Can't build URI.
Extracted source (around line #10):

```
    <%= link_to buzz, class: "buzz" do %>
      <%= image_tag(buzz.user_view_url) %>
      <div class="buzz-data">
        <h3 class="buzz-title is-size-5 is-uppercase"><%= buzz.title %></h3>
        <br />
```

The index action on my controller:

def index

```
@buzzs = Buzz.all.order('created_at DESC')
```

end

The issue occurs when a user does not upload an image or something funky happens with the uploading of an image, I get the error. Any in-depth walk-through of my problem and a solution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a validation on the user_view_url?

Comment: I don't believe I do. How or where would I validate it at?

Comment: Try something like this `<%= image_tag(buzz.user_view_url) if buzz.user_view_url %>`

Comment: Hey! It worked! Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain it bit further for me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `if` modifier to the call to `image_tag`. It will look something like this:

```
<%= image_tag(buzz.user_view_url) if buzz.user_view_url %>
```

What this does is displays the image_tag IF the user uploads an image. If the user doesn't upload an image, the image_tag will not be displayed. You can read more about if and if modifiers here: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html